# I can not make the page header

Tags: html, web, version-control, header

I just started doing this and nothing comes out
There is no text on the page, I do not know what is the problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN5Ib.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try and had this to the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

Also, be sure to save your work.